# iPhone Safari :last-child not rendering in table

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari, css-selectors

I have a responsive layout that, below a certain breakpoint, displays only the first and last columns of a table such to reduce the amount of space needed.

Here is the CSS...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    #content-container table thead th {
        display: none;
    }
    #content-container table thead th:first-child {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
    #content-container table thead th:last-child {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    #content-container table tbody tr td {
        display: none;
    }
    #content-container table tbody tr td:first-child {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
    #content-container table tbody tr td:last-child {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```

The HTML is just a simple table made of `table`, `thead`, `th`, `tbody`, `td` and also `a` attributes in the final column.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Flight</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th style="width: 140px;">Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td style="width: 140px;">
                <a style="display: inline-block;" href="#">Remove</a>
                <a style="display: inline-block;" href="#">Brief</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this produces strange results when rendering on the iPhone screen.
[image: Image showing how the last column is not rendering.]

As you can see, there is only one column. The last column hasn't rendered.

Rotating the device landscape and then returning it to portrait makes the final column display (sometimes), which is strange. See below.

[image: This shows what the table should actually look like.]

This problem is driving me up the wall and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle with this? It will be easier to look and change. And just as idea to test, try to set `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` on buttons and see will it fix this bug or not.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I could do, but it works perfectly on desktop - just not on iPhone! I will try your advice, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Quirksmode list](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html), it's supported but only for static content. A possible workaround is to give the columns classes instead.